# Cannot add named vertex (according to tutorial)

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I'm studying BGL now and I found a [tutorial](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/BoostGraphTutorial/blob/master/boost_graph_tutorial.pdf) for it. Everything worked fine from it until I reached  function to add_named_vertex. Here is a piece of code I have, that does not work as I (and tutorial) expect:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::directedS,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>
>
create_empty_graph() { return {}; }

template<typename graph, typename name_type>
typename boost::graph_traits<graph>::vertex_descriptor
add_named_vertex(const name_type& vertex_name, graph& g) noexcept {
    const auto vd = boost::add_vertex(g);
    auto vertex_name_map = get(boost::vertex_name, g);
    put(vertex_name_map, vd, vertex_name);
    return vd;
}

int main()
{
    auto g = create_empty_graph();
    const auto va = add_named_vertex("One", g);
    const auto vb = add_named_vertex("Two", g);
    boost::add_edge(va,vb, g);

    std::stringstream f;
    boost::write_graphviz(f, g);
    std::cout << f.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect:

```
digraph G {
0[label=One];
1[label=Two];
0->1;
}
```

But here is what I got:

```
digraph G {
0;
1;
0->1;
}
```

As you can see, there are no labels in the output of this code. Could you please tell me, what am I missing? Is it expected behavior?
Tried both clang++ and gcc and for range of Boost version (1.69 - 1.71).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is expectd behavior. To print the labels, add a property writer:

```
auto vlw = boost::make_label_writer(boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g));
boost::write_graphviz(f, g, vlw);
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b86ea256fde5314)

Or, as I prefer, use `write_graphviz_dp` to use `dynamic_properties`:

```
boost::dynamic_properties dp;
dp.property("node_id", boost::get(boost::vertex_index, g));
dp.property("label", boost::get(boost::vertex_name, g));
boost::write_graphviz_dp(f, g, dp);
```

See it [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8865bf868fbfeb3)

It may seem like more work, but it is easy and flexible with many vertex/edge properties. You can [search my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20dynamic_properties) for good examples of this.

Both the above solutions print

```
digraph G {
0[label=One];
1[label=Two];
0->1 ;
}
```

### BONUS

You don't need the `add_named_vertex` function. You can initialize the property directly with `boost::add_vertex`:

```
const auto va = add_vertex({"One"}, g);
const auto vb = add_vertex({"Two"}, g);
add_edge(va, vb, g);
```

Comment: Fixed search link

Comment: Great, thanks! I have a follow up question, if you don't mind =) Let's assume I have a bundled vertex property (some structure with fields .label, .shape, etc). How can I modify label write so that I can put HTML-like label? So far I noticed, that BGL put all my labels in quotes =( And if you know a good manual for BGL that would be more than appreciated =))

Comment: I'd write the Graphviz myself, or use their library (libcgraph IIRC?). Chances are very slim you can get the convenience helpers that BGL has to do that kind of advanced formatting for you. For background see https://github.com/sehe/spirit-graphviz/

Comment: Specifically: https://github.com/sehe/spirit-graphviz/blob/master/spirit-graphviz.cpp#L383 :)